# Selecting superset and subsets from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm dumb stuck while trying to invent the way to select certain data from a table. The sandbox  table looks like this:

```
|COL_1|COL_2|COL_3|
|-----|-----|-----|
|     |     |     |
|     | 2   |     |
|1    |     |     |
|4    | 3   |     |
|8    |     | 7   |
|     | 4   | 5   |
|1    | 6   | 3   |
```

The code for creating it is as follows:

```
create table tmp_224391 as (select 1 as col_1, 2 as Col_2, 3 as Col_3 from dual);
truncate table tmp_224391;

INSERT INTO tmp_224391 VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_224391 VALUES(NULL,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_224391 VALUES(1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_224391 VALUES(4,3,NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_224391 VALUES(8,NULL,7);
INSERT INTO tmp_224391 VALUES(NULL,4,5);
INSERT INTO tmp_224391 VALUES(1,6,3);
commit;
```

What I'm trying to do is to write a query to select either all rows or some rows depending on the value of the three variables (`:val_1`, `:val_2` and `:val_3`), each of which represent the column. So the hypothetic code looks somewhat like this:

```
select * from tmp_224391
 where 1=1
   and nvl(col_1,0) = nvl(:val_1,0)
   ...
```

The trick is that I need only the row(s) that contain 1 in COL_1 if `:val_1` = 1 (or only the rows with 4 in COL_1 if `:val_1` = 4. But in case `:val_1` is null - I need all the rows regardless of what is in `:val_1`.

For example:

- IF `:val_1 is null`, `:val_2 is null` and `:val_3 is null` - I need to get the entire table
- IF `:val_1 = 1`, `:val_2 is null` and `:val_3 is null` - I need to get rows

Sample:

```
|1    |     |     |
|1    | 6   | 3   |
```

How can I write such a select?

Comment: Is there a question here? If so please provide more detail and the expected results

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica, sorry, just finished polishing the post.

Comment: @Pugzly, sorry just finalized the post by adding details and expected results. Thank You.

Comment: I think you've missed a few cases that need to be clarified.  If you just mean "when :val_x IS NULL, this matches any col_x, even null", you should indicate that clearly.

Comment: And what is the question? *I need only the row(s) that contain 1 in COL_1 if :val_1 = 1* - `col1 =:val_1 and :val_1 is not null`. *But in case :val_1 is null* - `or :val_1 is null and ...` *I need all the rows regardless of what is in :val_1* - `... and 1 = 1`. Then all together: `(col1 =:val_1 and :val_1 is not null) or (:val_1 is null and 1 = 1)`. Remembering that null is not equal to anything, remove unnecessary conditions: `col1 =:val_1 or :val_1 is null`. Done

Answer (score 0):

```
...
where (col_1 = :val_1 or :val_1 is null)
  and (col_2 = :val_2 or :val_2 is null)
  and (col_3 = :val_3 or :val_3 is null)
  [and ... other conditions]
...
```

You could also rig this with `nvl` or who-knows-what, but it will be a pain to get it right (very easy to get it wrong) and also a pain for others to read the code in the future. The way I wrote it you can't get it wrong, and it's easy to read and understand right away.